# Weird Eclipse error on demo project

Tags: android, eclipse

I just imported a demo project and it contains one error. The error is underlining the "p" of package on the header of one class. See image below. I have run project clean, etc. Nothing gets rid of this weird erroneous error:

[image]

This project demo was download [from here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering#custom).

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? I've seen eclipse show some strange stuff but it doesn't affect execution.

Comment: it says your project has errors

Comment: Does it say anything if you hoover over 'p'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your `project > Properties > Android > Select an Android version.`

OR

If above solution is not eligible, you have most probably not added Google Map Api to your demo project, It can found [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

Comment: it has 4.3 set as its android version

Comment: select some lower version may be 3.0 and clean the project and rebuilt it

Comment: weird it just went away with out changing anything after the 4th clean